# May someone please assist me with this error?

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I am trying to create a basic todo app in flutter using Objectbox as a database.

This is the error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: ObjectBoxException: failed to create store:
> Incoming entity ID 1:2836062220106497081 does not match existing UID 524091579686138896

Answer (score 1):

From the ObjectBox's [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.objectbox.io/troubleshooting#dbschemaexception-incoming-id-does-not-match-existing-uid):

> This means there is a conflict between the data model defined in your code (using @Entity classes) and the data model of the existing database file.

In the [meta models docs](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/meta-model-ids-and-uids#resolving-meta-model-conflicts) it says:

> There are basically two ways to resolve this:
>
> - Resolve conflicts in or reconstruct the default.json meta model file to match the model of an existing database file.
> - Keep or create a fresh default.json model file and delete the database file. However, this will lose all existing data.